# GL_LINE_STIPPLE doesn't work as it should

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

So this should make a stippled triangle but all i get is normal lines. Any ideas why this issue may be caused?

```
private void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glViewport(0, 0 , 1000, 1000);
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    short  stipple = (short)0xAAAA;
    ((GL2) gl).glLineStipple( 1, stipple );
    gl.glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_STRIP);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 0.75f, 0);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.25f, 0);
    gl.glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.25f, 0);
    gl.glVertex3f(0f, 0.75f, 0);        
    gl.glEnd();  
    gl.glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);}
```

Comment: What's your `GL_VENDOR` and `GL_RENDERER`?

Comment: Note that `glLineStipple` has been removed in OpenGL 3.1+. I wouldn't be surprised if some vendors didn't implement it. Consider using shaders and the `discard` statement instead.

Comment: This should not make a stippled triangle under any stretch of the imagination. You are using a line strip with 4 vertices (which by the way could be simplified to a `GL_LINE_LOOP` with only 3). It will produce 3 line segments on the perimeter of a triangle.

Comment: Works for me. I tried it on my Mac with Intel graphics, and in C++. So either your driver is broken, or there's something funky going on with our Java bindings. With your parameters, the stippling is kind of hard to see on a high res display. Maybe try `0xFF00` instead to make the effect much more pronounced.

Comment: @RetoKoradi There is nothing funky with JOGL, it just calls the native methods. Andon is right and maybe there is a driver bug when using stippled lines in a line strip. Artur please look at this schema: http://glprogramming.com/red/images/Image34.gif Andon is right, you could use a line loop and keep only the first three vertices.

Comment: @gouessej: Not sure what your point is? The use of line stippling in the code is correct. I tried it. I suggested that it's a driver bug. Andon was completely wrong when he said that "this should not make a stippled triangle under any stretch of the imagination". The reason I mentioned the Java bindings is that the code casts a value  to `short` that is outside of the valid range for a `short`. I don't think it will do harm, but it looked weird. There's also a cast of `gl` to `GL2`, even though that is already its type, which does not make much sense, but is most likely also harmless.

Comment: @RetoKoradi yes the cast of gl to GL2 is useless as the declared type of gl is GL2.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: How was I completely wrong? In what world are three lines a triangle? This *may* produce 3 stippled lines, but it will not produce a stippled triangle ***ever***. If it produced a stippled triangle for you, then your driver has some serious issues.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: You need to use `glPolygonStipple (...)` in order to stipple a triangle and that is why this will never produce a stippled triangle, even if the correct primitive type were used.

Comment: Hey guys and sorry for my late reply. First of all i used GL_LINE_STRIP just to mess around with jogl, I am aware of the GL_LINE_LOOP. I guess that either my driver is going nuts or the glLineStipple has been simply removed in OpenGL 3.1+ as Colonel stated. It's a relatively small issue afterall so I'm not too too worried about it. Thanks for help everyone, I will try to mess with drivers and apply everything you all have suggested.
Thanks alot!

Comment: @Artur: `glLineStipple` has been removed from non-compatibility 3.1+. But so has `glVertex3f` and virtually everything else you called, so that is not your issue. But what you want are stippled lines, not a stippled triangle (which is a filled primitive). Stippling filled primitives requires something else altogether.